# If you target a Sheele in Soul Form with the Fuse spell, can you affect its maintenance cost?

Tags: spells, anima-beyond-fantasy

As per the title.  The current party I am in has a spellcaster with the Fuse spell (me), a Ki/Nemesis user (also me), and a summoner who has a Sheele with Soul Form (someone else).  We are currently wondering if casting the Fuse spell to fuse said Ki/Nemesis user with said Sheele allows us to discard the Zeon cost of the Sheele's Soul Form for the duration of the Fuse spell.

Text of the Sheele's Soul Form's costs:

> Each turn the transformation remains active, there is an additional cost equal to the Sheele's new Presence in Zeon Points. That is, a level 3 Sheele in Soul Form would cost 40 points of Zeon per turn.

Text of the Fuse spell (from the English *Anima: Beyond Fantasy* sourcebook):

> Unites two beings in a single body, creating a new individual who possesses the characteristics and abilities of both. The caster designates which capacities prevail, selecting those that he is interested in from each. If the spell joins a fighter and a psychic, for example, the resulting individual could have the fighting ability of the warrior, the mental powers of the mentalist, and the highest Secondary Abilities of each one. Control of the resulting united body falls to whichever of the two wins an Opposed Check of Willpower, although some characteristics typical of the other personality can be retained. The original bodies remain in the state they were in before the fusion and so, when the spell lapses, return to the state and condition they were in before it was cast. The death of the joint entity causes the death of both original people. The total Presence of both originals cannot be more than 80. It is also possible to Fuse an individual with objects, in which case the GM can award the result the advantages and abilities he considers appropriate.

Comment: Answers with broader comments upon the interaction of the Fuse spell with Sheele rules are also encouraged.

Comment: If there's more you want to know about the interactions between these two spells, please ask specific questions. We'd really prefer answers to stay focused on the actual content of your question.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes

When you use Fuse you pick what traits from each subject you want to keep.  If you want to keep the Zeon upkeep cost, you can.  If you don't, you don't have to.  Note that technically you are choosing the lack of Zeon upkeep from the other subject over the having of Zeon upkeep of the sheele when you make such a choice-- if you had two beings with Zeon upkeep, for example, this would no longer work.

Answer (score -1):

To pre-empt. Given the nature of the Sheele, this wouldn't really make sense in my opinion. The Sheele is an extension of the owner of the sheele's soul. Literally a piece of them. Even discarding that, why would their Soul form cease to consume Zeon if it is still in use?

Soul form is treated similar to an upkept spell, and the bonuses associated are a consequence of that. I would argue that the fused individual could still make use of the soul form, but its maintenance would still need to be payed.